# Algorithm to find entires of array summing to 0 in O(nlog(n)) time

Tags: algorithm, fft

I'm working on the following problem:

> Let A be an array of length n with each element -10n <= A[i] <= 10n. Create an algorithm running in O(nlog(n)) time that determines whether or not there exist entries A[i], A[j], and A[k] (i, j, and k not necessarily distinct) such that A[i] + A[j] + A[k] = 0.

I'm approaching it in the following way. Define a polynomial p of degree n-1 such that the coefficient on the x^k term is A[k]. Then [use the FFT to multiply p](https://www.cs.iastate.edu/~cs577/handouts/polymultiply.pdf) with itself, and then multiply the resulting polynomial again by p. If any of the coefficients in the resulting polynomial are 0, then return true. Else, return false. Since the FFT is O(nlog(n)), this algorithm is then O(nlog(n)).

The problem I'm running into is that the FFT combines like terms, so to speak. Thus, the existence of a coefficient 0 does not imply that such entries exist.

Could anyone suggest a modification to this algorithm to improve it?

Comment: What do you mean by combining "like terms"?

Comment: For instane, if q is the product of p with itself, the the coefficient on the x^6 term of q the sum of multiple coefficients computed when multiplying p by p.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember it right, the way to solve this problem is:

1. Define a polynomial of degree `60n + 1`, where the coefficient on the term `x^k` is number of occurrences of element `k - 10n` in the array. For instance, if `n=8`, the coefficient on `x^5` is number of occurrences of `-75` (`-75 = 5 - 10x8`)
2. Use FFT to raise that polynomial (of degree `60n + 1`) to the third power.
3. See if the coefficient on `x^(30n)` is non-zero. If it is, there's an answer.

Here's a sample implementation on python, it seems to work for all the cases I came up with:

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy.fft import fft, ifft

def hasZeroSum(a):
    n = len(a)
    b = [0 for x in range(n * 60 + 1)]
    for el in a: b[el + 10 * n] += 1
    f = fft(b, n * 60 + 1)
    f = np.power(f, 3)
    res = ifft(f, n * 60 + 1)
    return np.absolute(res[n * 30]) > 0.5

print hasZeroSum([-11, -5, 2, 3, 7])
print hasZeroSum([-11, -5, 2, 4, 8])
```

Prints

```
True
False
```

Comment: You imply that the elements are integers (or otherwize members of a countable set) which wasn't specified in the problem statement. Is this the case?

Comment: I inferred that from the fact that the elements are bounded. Bounds wouldn't make sense if the elements were not integers.